# New photo library in Photos.app

Tags: macos, photos, photos.app

How can I create a new, empty photo library in Photos, separated from my current library.

Answer (score 2):

When Photos.app starts, hold an Option Key ( ⌥ ). You will get a libraries manager.

[image]

When you select **Create New...** and save library, Photos will open a empty window and it is ready to use.

[image]